# password_hash() and password_verify() issues with Codeigniter 3.1.10

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, password-hash

I am trying to create a login/register function by using password_hash() and password_verify.

Here is the simple code that I wrote. The result that I get is "invalid Password" when I try to log in.

What am I missing?

**Register Controller**

```
 public function register() {
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $password = password_hash($this->input->post('password'), PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

 $insert_db = $this->db->insert('users',[
        'email' => $email, 
        'password' => $password
}
```

I can see that password_hash function seems to be fine, it storing random characters in the database. However, when I try to login with those details it doesn't work.

Database: field: varchar(255)

**Login controller:**

```
public function verifyLogin() {
 $email = $this->input->post('email');
 $password = ($this->input->post('pswd'));

 // load model 
 $this->load->model('Login_model');
 $account = $this->Login_model->verifyLogin($email, $password);

 if ($account) {
  //if user found, show success msg
    echo "successful login";
  } else {
    echo "invalid password";
  }

}
```

**Login Model**

```
 public function verifyLogin($email, $password) { 
    $query = $this->db->where([ 'email'=> $email])
                      ->get('users');

    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {

            // hash fetched from db 
            $record = $query->row();
            $dbPassword = $record->password;

            // Hash length showing 60         
               echo strlen($dbPassword);

            if (password_verify($password, $dbPassword)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

    }

    }
```

**Login Form**

```
<?= form_open('Login/verifyLogin'); ?>
<label>Email</label>
?php echo form_error('login-email);'?>
<?php echo form_input(['name'=>'login-email', 'value' => set_value('login-email')]); ?>
<label>Password</label>
<?php echo form_error('login-password'); ?>
<?php echo form_password(['name'=>'login-password', 'value' => set_value('login-password')]);?>
 <?php echo form_submit(['type' => 'submit', 'value' => 'Login']); ?>
<?= form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: what is the lengh of password field in db ? and can we see a example of hash fetched from db and hash length using strlen function. Also can you share the code that will insert to database.

Comment: What have you actually done to test this? Plonking up some not so simple code without any data i.e what you put in and what came out, would help.

Comment: length of the password field is varchar(255), I have updated my code, I have added the registration code and added the hash fetched from DB and hash length.

Thanks for any help.  @MohdAlomar.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw- I have created a registration form to store users information in the database and I have hashed the user's password by using password_hash(). Now when I am trying to login with the stored information through my login page password_verify() function isn't working properly and instead of logging in it shows an error. I have also updated my code so now you can have a better understanding. Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: To add further: I have tried to encrypt the password coming from login input field directly as well but doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Ibadullah I mean by add to add the value so we can see it like give us a example of a hash fetched from db and what is the length you give us values not code.

Comment: @MohdAlomar 

This is the value stored in my database table

'$2y$10$cz3WWqesmlKPekT7JrKLIOtrKHLDB6SsVX9ruE8TlrdJLAyXPNjcm'

Comment: Can you add the form code?

Comment: @MohdAlomar I have updated the code. please check you want for register as well?

Answer (score 0):

you have two mistakes

your password field name is `login-password` but you trying to get `pswd` also if user not found you should return false

Also for email it is the same your form name is `login-email` but your are trying to access `email`

```
public function verifyLogin() {
 $email = $this->input->post('login-email');
 $password = ($this->input->post('login-password'));

 // load model 
 $this->load->model('Login_model');
 $account = $this->Login_model->verifyLogin($email, $password);

 if ($account) {
  //if user found, show success msg
    echo "successful login";
  } else {
    echo "invalid password";
  }

}
```

and

```
public function verifyLogin($email, $password) { 
    $query = $this->db->where([ 'email'=> $email])
                      ->get('users');

    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {

            // hash fetched from db 
            $record = $query->row();
            $dbPassword = $record->password;

            // Hash length showing 60         
               echo strlen($dbPassword);

            if (password_verify($password, $dbPassword)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
    }
    return false;

 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the two mistakes you mentioned, I already fixed that but it wasn't working now I copy-paste your code and it's working perfectly fine. No idea what was wrong before. thanks you so much :)

Comment: your welcome maybe you had typo in code but password_verify was working but I think your code never execute it

Answer (score -1):

Your code seem's working I tested ..

Comment: Which Codeigniter version you tested on? Because this doesn't work for anyone I know? :S

Comment: I am using 3.1.10 version

Comment: It outputs "invalid password" every time I put the correct or wrong password.

Comment: your password field name is login-password but you trying to get pswd also if user not found you should return false